# Min max of a quadratic form of plus-minus ones

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, fourier-analysis, eigenvalues, hypercube

Does the following limit exist?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,  n^{-3/2} \min_{a_{ij}=\pm 1}\max_{x_{j}=\pm 1}\left|\sum_{1\leq i <j \leq n} a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j} \right|
$$
There is no any significant motivation behind this question, it is just a pure curiosity.

I am not really interested in numerical computations, and proofs of  upper or lower bounds unless they provide significant evidence that the limit does not exist. In case the limit exists I am curious what is the proof?

Comment: As the absolute value does not really change anything (by symmetry), the answer to your question equals to $\frac 12 \lim_{n \to \infty}\, min_A max_x n^{-3/2} x^TAx$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ size $\pm 1$ matrix and $x\in \{\pm 1\}^n$. Because of this, I think that you should use very different tags for your question.

Comment: @domotorp why can you remove the absolute value?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I take that part back. Still, I feel that this has more to do with eigenvalues than with discrepancy.

Comment: I added eigenvalues too. I wish I could also add: spin-glasses, polynomials, maxCut, Littlewoods 4/3 inequality, ... the limit of number of tags is <6

Comment: The limsup is definitely finite by Talagrand's results (because if you chose the $A$ matrix randomly, instead of taking the minimum over all such $A$'s then the limit exists, and taking the minimum instead of the expectation is definitely no larger). One possibility is that the limit exists and equals 0.

Comment: @ShannonStarr 
I agree with upper bounds. Lower bounds are more tricky. I can show that liminf is at least $C>0$.  If my calculus is correct  then $C=2^{-5/2}$ works. Perhaps I can do better than $2^{-5/2}$, but these arguments that I know do not prove/disprove existence of the limit.

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili That is impressive. I was wrong to quickly suggest the limit is 0. I would be interested in knowing your proof. I would think that some of the complexity people might be knowledgeable about this, like Cris Moore, or maybe Lenka Zdeborova. But also, the large-deviations people who are former students of Gerard Ben Arous should be interested, like Aukosh Jagganath, because you are proving lower bounds that rule-in or rule-out certain large deviation bounds. But you probably know better than me who to share this with.

Comment: https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i4p10/pdf I think the idea of this paper could be useful. Break your $K_n$ graph into 2 roughly equal parts and focus on the $a_{ij}$'s between the two parts. After taking care of that, for choosing the matrix entries interior to each of the 2 parts, iterate. But that paper by Garry Bowlin probably does not have good enough results to be helpful. It is just a potentially interesting connection.

Comment: @ShannonStarr, here is one way to get a lower bound, see Theorem of Defant--Mastylo--Perez applied to 2-homogeneous polynomial f, https://extremal010101.wordpress.com/2019/12/06/a-little-bit-of-fourier-analysis/    Thanks for the references and the names.